# does deploying multiple instances of a verticle for creating a httpserver use multiple threading for handling requests?

Tags: multithreading, vert.x, event-loop, vertx-verticle, java-vertx-web

I want my vertx application to use multiple threads ( multiple event loops ) to take advantage of multiple cores and handles requests more optimally. Hence, I have deployed multiple instances of the server init verticle.

But it doesn't seem like it is using separate event loops to handle concurrent requests.

```
App.java
__________
package org.example;

import io.vertx.core.DeploymentOptions;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle("org.example.ServerVertcle",new DeploymentOptions().setInstances(8));
    }
}

ServerVertcle.java
____________________
package org.example;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;

public class ServerVertcle extends AbstractVerticle {

    public void start() {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx);
        router.route("/api").blockingHandler(ctx -> {
            System.out.println("Started at : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            try {Thread.sleep(5000); } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            System.out.println("After timeout : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
           ctx.end("Hello World");
        });
        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router).listen(8000).onSuccess(server -> {
           System.out.println("Server Started in thread: "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        });
    }

    public void stop() {}
}

output:
Started at : 1667678335486
After timeout : 1667678340486
Started at : 1667678340496
After timeout : 1667678345496
Started at : 1667678345500
After timeout : 1667678350500
```

I have concurrently triggered 3 get requests to the /api endpoint and it seems that each request is handled sequentially and not concurrently. how can I change this behaviour to take advantage of the multi-reactor pattern ?

Comment: Share your "triggered 3 requests code"

Comment: All3 requests are GET 127.0.0.1:8000. just simple get requests